# Java 8: Building initials from nullable first name and last name

Tags: java

Looking for a better way or existing library that'll allow more elegant way of constructing initials. Current thing I got seems a bit clumsy:

```
String first = Optional.ofNullable(person.getFirstName()).orElse("");
first = first.isEmpty() ? first : first.substring(0, 1);

String last = Optional.ofNullable(person.getLastName()).orElse("");
last = last.isEmpty() ? last : last.substring(0, 1);

return first + last;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// extract common code to method to avoid duplication
private String getInitial(String s) {
    return (s != null && !s.isEmpty()) ? s.substring(0, 1) : "";
}

private String getInitials(Person person) {
    return getInitial(person.getFirstName()) + getInitial(person.getLastName());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map`:

```
String first = Optional.ofNullable(person.getFirstName())
                   .map(s -> s.substring(0, 1)).orElse("");
```

(Are you using Java 8's `Optional`? That doesn't have `fromNullable` and `or` methods - it has `ofNullable` and `orElse` methods instead).

Using Google Guava's `Optional` instead of Java 8's:

```
String first = Optional.fromNullable(person.getFirstName())
                   .transform(s -> s.substring(0, 1)).or("");
```

Comment: fromNullable is probably from guava

Comment: Yes, but why is he then mentioning Java 8 in the title?

Comment: That's embarrassing, sorry :) I fixed the question - it now uses proper Java 8 syntax.

Comment: This will throw an exception if the string is empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
final class NameUtils
{

  static String initials(Person p)
  {
    Stream<String> s = Stream.of(p.getFirstName(), p.getLastName());
    return s.filter(NameUtils::isValid).map(x -> x.substring(0, 1)).collect(Collectors.joining());
  }

  private static boolean isValid(String s)
  {
    return (s != null) && (s.length() > 0);
  }

}
```

Comment: @JBNizet Good suggestion. I agree, this is overkill, but I took it the OP wanted to understand a functional approach.

Comment: This defo is the most epic functional approach, but I guess that JB Nizet's solution is a bit more readable for the most Java devs :)